# Tunneling my internet connection through a remote server with SSH

Tags: ssh, proxy, ssh-tunnel

I'm based in the UK and would like to proxy my browser traffic through a CentOS server I have set up in the US. From what I've gathered through Google if I execute a command like this on my server:

```
ssh -C2qTnN -D 8080 username@remote_host
```

It will set up a SSH tunnel on my server for `127.0.0.1:8080` pointing to `username@remote_host`. But how do I set up a basic proxy (I don't need any encryption) so I can plonk in an `ip:port` into my web browsers proxy settings and proxy through my remote server when browsing the internet?

Answer (score 0):

You already *did* set up the proxy! The `-D` option causes sshd to run a local SOCKS proxy on the specified port. Now all that remains is for you to configure your browser to use it.

Comment: Alright, so in my browser settings I put `server_ip:8080` and browse as normal? Won't I be resitrcted to the `remote_host` rather than being able to browse the interwebs?

Comment: No, your connections are proxied _through_ the remote host. Didn't you already try this?!?